# Skip Rows in CSV Containing Specific String

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, for-loop

I have a list of strings (longer than in this example). If one of the strings exists in a row of data, I want to skip that row. This is what I have so far but I get an index error, which leads me to believe I'm not looping correctly.

```
stringList = ["ABC", "AAB", "AAA"]

with open('filename.csv', 'r')as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(filereader, None) #Skip header row
    for row in filereader:
        for k in stringList:
            if k not in row:
                data1 = column[1]
```

The error I get: `IndexError: list index out of range`. I realize I'm reading by row, but I need to extract the data by column.

Comment: I don't see `column` assigned anywhere.

Comment: If your CSV has headers I recommend using `DictReader`

Comment: replace `data1 = column[1]`  by `data1 = row[1]`. if required add check for len(row)>1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `row` is a list and you are using/accessing it as a normal variable.
You can access certain columns by using appropriate indexing of the list row. Eg: in the first iteration `row[0]` will be the element in the first-row first-column, `row[1]` the second column entry and so on. On subsequent iterations of `row`, you can access entries of subsequent column downwards.

Here's a simple loop to do it.

```
for row in filereader:
        for k in stringList:
            for i in range(len(row)):
                if k not in row[i]:
                    someVar=row[i]
```

Comment: This results in an error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Did you mean `range(len(row))`?

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry for that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With pandas you can do it easily, with a mask. See more: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html)

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
data = data.loc[data['column_name'] not in stringList]
```